# Plotting far away objects in a 3D plot, Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have the 3D plot of an orbit around the Earth and the surface plot of the Earth itself. I want to see the Sun in the right spot too, but if I plot the surface plot of the Sun, the plot zooms out too much. I want to see only objects near Earth, while being able to spot the Sun in the distance. Do you have any tips to achieve that?
I have the relative position of the Sun wrt the Earth, the Earth center is the origin of the plot.
P.S.: I can zoom in the plot but results are not nearly good enough. Earth is so small that the zoom stops working before reaching it
This is the plot as of now:
[image]

This is the plot without the Sun:
[image]

This is the code (plot only):

```
figure('Color','k');
%rotate3d;
% Black background and planets
%background('Black');
%hold on
% Celestial bodies
p3Dopts.Units = 'km';
%p3Dopts.RotAngle = 180;
planet3D('Earth', p3Dopts);
hold on
%p3Dopts.Position = rSun(1,:)';
%planet3D('Sun', p3Dopts);
% Flight path
scatter3( Y(:,1), Y(:,2), Y(:,3), 6, scaledT)
xlabel('x [km]'); ylabel('y [km]'); zlabel('z [km]');
ylim([-40000,40000]);
title('Earth equatorial frame', 'FontSize', 14);
cbar = colorbar; cbar.Color = 'w'; cbar.Title.Color = 'w';
cbar.Title.String = strcat('Time [',Tname,']');
clim([min(scaledT);max(scaledT)])   
axis equal;
grid on;
ax = gca; ax.Color = 'k'; ax.GridColor = 'w';
ax.GridAlpha = 0.45; ax.XColor = 'w'; ax.YColor = 'w';
ax.ZColor = 'w';
hold off
```

Comment: You could put a light source where the sun is.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I will try it, it's a good idea

Comment: @CrisLuengo It works perfectly to iluminate the planet itself, it's a nice to have in these plots. Here is the code:
```
%Sunlight
light("Style","local","Position",rSun(1,:));
```
However i would still love to see the sun or the moon. Maybe working out a 2d projection in some way

Answer (score 1):

```
ax = gca;  % Get the current axes object
ax.Projection = 'orthographic';
ax.CameraPosition = [0, 0, 1];  % Set the camera position to be above the plot

ax.XLim = [-40000, 40000];  % Set the x-axis range
ax.YLim = [-40000, 40000];  % Set the y-axis range
ax.ZLim = [-40000, 40000];  % Set the z-axis range
```

Comment: The Sun is outside the plot and therefore we can't see it (i just tried), but i gotta admit your projection is so good for this kind of project. Add a "rotate3d" so you can move around and it's a good result. I will try mixing this solution with Cris Luengo's

Answer (score 1):

Edit 1: Updated the code. Instead of doing the 68º FOV part, I'm setting the camva value (camera view angle) to twice the angle given by the tangent of r-R over r, which works amazingly. I also set the sun as a bright sphere instead of using planet3D, which tries to plot an image over it but since the sphere will always be small in this instance (and very bright), there is no point. Here is the video result, a small taste of it:
https://youtu.be/QJ8t8ZHh_j8

I ended up doing a mixture of solutions. Thanks @Marco, @Cris Luengo from Stack Overflow and @Karim from Matlab's forum.

- `r` is the camera position relative to the origin like everything else.
- `dist` is half the distance of one of the sides of the cube displayed. I decided to use the orbital height multiplied by tan(68º), based on human horizontal FOV.
- `rSun` is the position vector of the sun.
- `rMoon` (drawing this one too) is the position vector of the moon.

If the object is extremely far away like the sun you can drop the denominator's r.

If the object is itself a light source (the sun), you need another light source (but local) between the observer located in r, and the sun.

Here is the entire code for the plot in case you want it.

```
r = Y(j,1:3);
trackT = (rotRz(deg2rad(-angleEarth(j)))*track')';
dist = norm(r);%tand(68)*(norm(r)-Rearth);
figure('Color','k','Position', [0 0 screen(3) screen(4)]);

% Celestial bodies
p3Dopts.Units = 'km';
p3Dopts.RotAngle = angleEarth(j);
planet3D('Earth Cloudy', p3Dopts);
hold on
p3Dopts = rmfield(p3Dopts, 'RotAngle');
sunRelPos = normalize(rSun(j,:),'norm')*dist';
sunRelSize = 2.1*Rsun/norm(rSun(j,:))*norm(sunRelPos-r);
[sunX,sunY,sunZ]=sphere;
sunX = sunX*sunRelSize+sunRelPos(1);
sunY = sunY*sunRelSize+sunRelPos(2);
sunZ = sunZ*sunRelSize+sunRelPos(3);
surf(sunX,sunY,sunZ,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor',[0.98;0.843;0.627],'AmbientStrength',1,'SpecularStrength',1,'SpecularExponent',500)
%Sunlight, apparent Sun is ~28-34 arc minutes near Earth
light("Style","infinite","Position",sunRelPos)
light("Style","local","Position",sunRelPos+normalize(r-sunRelPos,'norm')*2*sunRelSize);
p3Dopts.Position = normalize(rMoon(j,:),'norm')*dist';
p3Dopts.Size = norm(p3Dopts.Position-r)/norm(rMoon(j,:)-r);
planet3D('Moon', p3Dopts);
p3Dopts = rmfield(p3Dopts, 'Position');
p3Dopts = rmfield(p3Dopts, 'Size');
% Ground track
scatter3(trackT(1:j,1), trackT(1:j,2), trackT(1:j,3), 12, T(1:j), 'filled')
% Current point, so the plot doesn't get distorted
%scatter3(r(1),r(2),r(3),1)
%xlabel('x [km]'); ylabel('y [km]'); zlabel('z [km]');
title('Earth focused animation');  
axis equal;
grid on;
ax = gca; ax.Color = 'k'; ax.GridColor = 'k';
ax.GridAlpha = 0; ax.XColor = 'k'; ax.YColor = 'k';
ax.ZColor = 'k';

ax.CameraPosition = r;  % Set the camera position
camva(2*rad2deg(atan((norm(r)-Rearth)/norm(r))));
ax.XLim = [-dist, dist];  % Set the x-axis range
ax.YLim = [-dist, dist];  % Set the y-axis range
ax.ZLim = [-dist, dist];  % Set the z-axis range

hold off
```